# WooCommerce - reload the order on click of a button via Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I'm adding a 'Remove' button next to each item in the Order via this function in functions.php:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'display_remove_order_item_button', 10, 3 );
function display_remove_order_item_button( $item_id, $item, $order ){
    // Avoiding displaying buttons on email notification
    if( ! ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'view-order' ) || is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) ) return;

    if( isset($_POST["remove_item_$item_id"]) && $_POST["remove_item_$item_id"] == 'Remove this item' ){
        wc_delete_order_item( $item_id );
    }

    echo '<form class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style= "margin-top:12px;">
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="remove_item_'.$item_id.'" value="Remove this item" />
    </form>';
}
```

The issue is, after clicking the Remove button you then have to refresh the order page in order for the item to disappear.

I'd like that to happen automatically. I suppose I need to use Ajax to call the above function, but not quite sure how to do that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your example is working, you'll change the function to look something like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'display_remove_order_item_button', 10, 3 );
function display_remove_order_item_button( $item_id, $item, $order ){
    // Avoiding displaying buttons on email notification
    if( ! ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'view-order' ) || is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) ) return;

    echo '<form class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style= "margin-top:12px;">
<input type="submit" id="remove-btn" data-id="'.$item_id.'" data-order="'.$order->get_order_number().'" class="button" name="remove_item_'.$item_id.'" value="Remove this item" />
    </form>';
}
```

We gave the button a unique ID so we can detect clicks using jQuery. Notice `data-id` attribute, that's where we're passing $item_id. Now that display function is ready, we need to create an ajax call:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'ajax_call_remove_item');
function ajax_call_remove_item() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript" >
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(document).on("click","#remove-btn",function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    // get data values from the button
        var details = $(this).data();
        var container = $(this).closest('td').parent('tr');
      $(this).closest('td').append('<div id="loader">Data is loading</div>');
        var data = {
            action: 'remove_item',
            // get id from data
            id: details.id,
            orderid: details.order,
        };

        $.post('<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', data, function(response) {
           // display the response
           $(container).empty();       
           $(container).html(response);       
        });

    });
});

</script>
<?php
}
```

Now a function to handle POST data, delete the item and return a response:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_remove_item', 'remove_item_callback_wp');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_remove_item', 'remove_item_callback_wp' );
function remove_item_callback_wp() {
     $item_id = $_POST['id'];
     $order_id = $_POST['orderid'];

    $order    = new WC_Order($order_id);


    foreach ($order->get_items() as $order_item_id => $item){
        if($order_item_id == $item_id){
            wc_delete_order_item(absint($order_item_id));
        }
    }


     echo "This items has been removed";

     exit(); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That seems to be working. It displays: "This order has been removed" and the item disappears on page refresh. However is it possible for it to get removed from the page without refreshing?

Comment: One issue I've noticed is that it only works for 1 item. Then if you click on 'Remove Item' on another item it still deletes it, however it's stuck on 'Data is loading'.

Comment: @Adrian I edited the jQuery code to remove the item from order page when deleted. This is tested and working, if you have any issue please do your own debugging as it must be related to your setup or other variables. If this helps please check it as the answer.

Comment: Works great. Thank you